# In Cell O6 I am checking to see if cell A6 is a public holiday, is so then place a "1" in cell O6, else "2". However cell Q6 will not calculate

Tags: microsoft-excel, cells, conditional-statements, if, blank

In Cell 06 I am checking to see if cell A6 is a public holiday, is so then place a "1" in cell O6, else "2". However cell Q6 will not calculate.

For some reason it will not see the number displayed and will not display the calculation.

[image]

Comment: please add the cell formula as text, not as a picture ... also add the formula in Q6

Comment: no ... the formula and any new information belongs in the question, not in a comment ... please use the edit button to update your question ...then delete the comments

Comment: What is  `N97` in your formula?

Comment: And what have you done to achieve this? This is not a free scripting site. It is a site that helps people who have helped themselves. So this site can help you with your code if you have any issues with your code. Feel free to share your code and we can help you debug your code. But we cannot code anything for you from scratch.

Answer (score -1):

In `O6` try:

```
=IF(OR(A6=$J$91:$J$103),"1","2")
```